# Celery Mongo backend not working as expected

Tags: python, mongodb, rabbitmq, celery

I'm working on a project on Kubernetes using Flask and Celery. My setup consists of using Rabbitmq as a broker and Mongodb as result backend. I've the following containers in my K8s pod: the api, a Celery worker, RabbitMQ and Mongodb.

Everything seems to work fine but the result backend.

This is my following celery configuration file:

```py
from os import environ
from typing import List, Union
from kombu import Queue, Exchange

broker_type: str = "amqp"
backend_type: str = 'mongodb'
backend_host: str = environ.get("MONGO_CELERY_HOST", "")
backend_port: str = environ.get("MONGO_CELERY_PORT", "")
backend_db: str = environ.get("MONGO_CELERY_DB", "")
backend_collection: str = environ.get("MONGO_CELERY_COLLECTION", "")

rabbitmq_user: str = environ.get("RABBITMQ_USER", "")
rabbitmq_password: str = environ.get("RABBITMQ_PASSWORD", "")
rabbitmq_host: str = environ.get("RABBITMQ_HOST", "")
rabbitmq_port: str = environ.get("RABBITMQ_PORT", "")
rabbitmq_virtual_host: str = environ.get("RABBITMQ_VIRTUAL_HOST", "")

broker_url: str = "{}://{}:{}@{}:{}{}".format(
  broker_type,
  rabbitmq_user,
  rabbitmq_password,
  rabbitmq_host,
  rabbitmq_port,
  rabbitmq_virtual_host
)

result_backend: str = "{}://{}:{}/".format(
  backend_type,
  backend_host,
  backend_port
)

mongodb_backend_settings = {
    'database': backend_db,
    'taskmeta_collection': backend_collection
}

accept_content: List[str] = ["pickle", "json", "application/json"]
result_serializer: str = "pickle"
task_serializer: str = "pickle"
enable_utc: bool = True
timezone: str = "UTC"
result_expires: int = 600
result_persistent: bool = False
requests_exchange = Exchange(name='requests_tasks', type='topic')

task_queues = [
    Queue(
        name='requests.queue',
        exchange=requests_exchange,
        routing_key='requests.tasks.*'
    )
]

task_default_queue: str = "requests.queue"
task_ack_late: bool = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier: int = 1
```

And my celery.py file:

```py
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery(
  "async_tasks",
  include=["async_tasks.tasks"]
)

celery_app.config_from_object("async_tasks.celeryconfig")
```

Inside `async_tasks.tasks` I have a `main_task` which I call when I receive a request to my service in the way `t = main_task.s().delay(args)`. I've an endpoint to perform the task (since it takes a few seconds-minutes to complete) and another to get the tasks results.

Here's where the problem comes in. The first endpoint gives me the `task_id` that I use in the second endpoint to create an `AsyncResult` instance as `result = AsyncResult(task_id)` but as soon as I call `result.ready()` or `result.status` to know about the task status it throws the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 475, in state
    return self._get_task_meta()['status']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 414, in _get_task_meta
    return self._maybe_set_cache(self.backend.get_task_meta(self.id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 451, in get_task_meta
    meta = self._get_task_meta_for(task_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 207, in _get_task_meta_for
    'result': self.decode(obj['result']),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 183, in decode
    return super(MongoBackend, self).decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 329, in decode
    accept=self.accept)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 263, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 54, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 194, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 50, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 263, in loads
    return decode(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 337, in unpickle
    return pickle_loads(str_to_bytes(s))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 59, in pickle_loads
    return load(BytesIO(s))
kombu.exceptions.DecodeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

The result is actually being stored into Mongodb, but can't be retrieved the way I want.
Previously I've worked using Redis as broker and backend and didn't have this problem.

This is my requirements file for the api and worker containers in the K8s pod:

```
amqp==2.5.2
Celery==4.4.0
Click==7.0
Cython==0.29.13
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
kombu==4.6.8
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pymongo==3.10.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
redis==3.3.8
requests==2.23.0
six==1.12.0
Unidecode==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

I'd be really glad if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set `result_serializer` to `json` instead of `pickle`.

Comment: @TomášLinhart I tried but didn't work, only changing `result_serializer: str = "json"` throws the following exception: `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict`, which is similar to the one I had using the `result_serializer` as `pickle`. So I decided to change everything to JSON (`task_serializer`, `result_serializer` and `accept_content`) but as the previous one, it throws and exception: `kombu.exceptions.DecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`.

Comment: Probably relates to [this issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5917) which I think was fixed in Celery 4.4.1. So please try to upgrade Celery and check.

Comment: Thanks @TomášLinhart, I'll try upgrading and then I'll post the results.

Comment: Hello again, finally I was able to perform tests. In fact, a version switch worked perfectly setting the task and result serializers as JSON. Tested with Celery 4.4.1.
Thank you so much @TomášLinhart. :D